# How can I draw an asymptotic bode plot?

Tags: plotting, control-systems

When I use *Mathematica* to draw a bode plot, it always gives the precise version, like this:

```
BodePlot[(10 (s + 3))/(s (s + 2) (s^2 + s + 2))]
```

[image]

How can I draw the asymptotic version, the kind where `1/(1 + jw)` is represented as a -20dB straight line but not a curve?

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can draw the asymptotes using `Epilog`.
The frequencies of interest are the max and min values and the corner frequencies.

```
tfm = (10 (3 + s))/(s (2 + s) (2 + s + s^2));
minF = Log10[0.001];
maxF = Log10[100];
cF1 = Log10[Sqrt[2]];
cF2 = Log10[2];
cF3 = Log10[3];
xcoords = {minF, cF1, cF2, cF3, maxF};
```

The magnitude at the lowest frequency.

```
mag0 = 20 Log10@Abs[tfm /. s -> I 0.001];
```

The magnitudes computed at the other frequencies of interest based on the slopes of the asymptotes. For example, between $minF$ and $cF1$ the slope is -20 db/decade.

```
ls = {mag0, -20 (cF1 - minF), -60 (cF2 - cF1), -80 (cF3 - 
  cF2), -60 (maxF - cF3)};
ycoords = FoldList[Plus, ls[[1]], ls[[2 ;; -1]]];
```

Finally render the plot.

```
BodePlot[tfm, Epilog -> {{Dashed, Line[Thread[{xcoords, ycoords}]]}, {}}][[1, 1, 1]]
```

[image]

The same process repeated for 10/(s+1).

```
tfm = 10/(s + 1);
minF = Log10[0.001];
maxF = Log10[100];
cF1 = Log10[1];
xcoords = {minF, cF1, maxF};
mag0 = 20 Log10@Abs[tfm /. s -> I 0.001];
ls = {mag0, 0, -20 (maxF - cF1)};
ycoords = FoldList[Plus, ls[[1]], ls[[2 ;; -1]]];
BodePlot[tfm, Epilog -> {{Dashed, Line[Thread[{xcoords, ycoords}]]}, {}}][[1,1,1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! maybe I could try to convert this to a more general function. Matlab's already got bode_as() by  Valerio Scordamaglia, though. But Mathematica's results look much better.