# Finite Poles and Zeros Approximation of a Transfer Function Having Cylindrical Functions

Tags: special-functions, control-systems

I have the following expression containing cylindrical functions:

```
c = HankelH2[1, s]/(HankelH2[1, s] + I HankelH2[0, s]);
```

I wish to find the approximate transfer function with 2 poles and 2 zeros. I've tried `PadeApproximant[]` but I'm getting nowhere near what I'm looking for (as found in [this work](http://dx.doi.org/10.2514/3.9545)):

$ \bar{c}=\frac{0.5(is+0.135)(is+0.651)}{(is+0.0965)(is+0.4555)}$

For those interested the transfer function above is the Theodorsen lift deficiency function.

I would also like to see the Bode plot of both the original function and its approximation.

*EDIT*

This problem is related to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27518/how-can-i-draw-an-asymptotic-bode-plot) question as indeed finding the rational approximation of Theodorsen's function is equivalent to finding the asymptotic Bode plot of it. The point is that anyhow I still can't even figure out how to plot it yet, as I believe *Mathematica* only accepts rational form transfer functions.

**EDIT 2**

As pointed out by @AccidentalFourierTransform the Theodorsen function has a branch cut along the negative real axis. As s originally is defined to be imaginary, I wouldn't worry about the meaning of it at the negative real axis: we may assume that its analytic continuation is restricted to the positive real axis.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the rational approximation you have, or did you come up with it yourself?

Comment: Seeing the paper, you could have clarified that $s=ik$; no wonder there was an apparent mismatch between the complex expression for Theodorsen's function and the real rational function.

Comment: @J.M. you are right. Yet in my edit I added yesterday I've said so: " As s originally is defined to be imaginary, I wouldn't worry about the meaning of it at the negative real axis: we may assume that its analytic continuation is restricted to the positive real axis."

Comment: I'm not sure how they exactly did their claim of a least-squares fit, but this is what I obtained from Padé approximation + matching at $k=0$ and $k=\infty$: `((1/4 (3 - Sqrt[3]) + I k) (1/4 (3 + Sqrt[3]) + I k))/(2 (1/8 (5 - Sqrt[13]) + I k) (1/8 (5 + Sqrt[13]) + I k))`.

Comment: @J.M. What do you mean with "matching"?

Comment: You'll notice that the function I supplied, call it `f[k]`, satisfies `f[0] == 1` and `Limit[f[x], x -> ∞] == 1/2`.